# How to show search marker with title and hide others marker using TextWatcher in android map

Tags: android, json, google-maps

I retrieve several marker from database using JSON and PHP , Now I want to search marker by title and show that marker with title and hide other marker.

**Here is java code**

```
public class MainActivity extends FragmentActivity {

    private GoogleMap googleMap;
    private List<Marker> markers = new ArrayList<>();

    // Search EditText
    EditText inputSearch;

    @Override
    protected void onCreate(Bundle savedInstanceState) {
        super.onCreate(savedInstanceState);
        setContentView(R.layout.activity_main);
        SupportMapFragment fragment = (SupportMapFragment) getSupportFragmentManager()
                .findFragmentById(R.id.map);
        googleMap = fragment.getMap();
        //  googleMap.setMyLocationEnabled(true);
        new RetrieveTask().execute();

        inputSearch = (EditText) findViewById(R.id.editText);

        inputSearch.addTextChangedListener(new TextWatcher() {

            @Override
            public void onTextChanged(CharSequence s, int start, int before, int count) {
                // When user changed the Text
                showMarker(s.toString());
            }


            @Override
            public void beforeTextChanged(CharSequence s, int start, int count, int after) {
                // TODO Auto-generated method stub

            }

            @Override
            public void afterTextChanged(Editable s) {
                // TODO Auto-generated method stub    

            }
        });
    }

    private void showMarker(String s) {

        for (Marker marker : markers) {

            if (marker.getTitle().equalsIgnoreCase(name)) {
                marker.setVisible(true);
                marker.showInfoWindow();
            } else {
                marker.setVisible(false);
            }
        }
    }   




    private class RetrieveTask extends AsyncTask<Void, Void, String> {
        @Override
        protected String doInBackground(Void... params) {
            String strUrl = "http://192.168.43.229/location_marker_mysql/retrieve.php";
            URL url = null;
            StringBuffer sb = new StringBuffer();

            try {
                url = new URL(strUrl);
                HttpURLConnection connection = (HttpURLConnection) url.openConnection();
                connection.connect();
                InputStream iStream = connection.getInputStream();
                BufferedReader reader = new BufferedReader(new InputStreamReader(iStream));
                String line = "";
                while ((line = reader.readLine()) != null) {
                    sb.append(line);
                }

                reader.close();
                iStream.close();

            } catch (MalformedURLException e) {
                e.printStackTrace();
            } catch (IOException e) {
                e.printStackTrace();
            }
            return sb.toString();
        }

        @Override
        protected void onPostExecute(String result) {
            super.onPostExecute(result);
            new ParserTask().execute(result);

       }
    }

    MarkerOptions markerOptions = new MarkerOptions();
    String name;
    LatLng latLng;
    double lat;
    double lng;

    private class ParserTask extends AsyncTask<String, Void, List<HashMap<String, String>>> {
        @Override
        protected List<HashMap<String, String>> doInBackground(String... params) {
            MarkerJSONParser markerParser = new MarkerJSONParser();
            JSONObject json = null;
            try {
                json = new JSONObject(params[0]);
            } catch (JSONException e) {
                e.printStackTrace();
            }
            List<HashMap<String, String>> markersList = markerParser.parse(json);
            return markersList;
        }

        @Override
        protected void onPostExecute(List<HashMap<String, String>> result) {
            for (int i = 0; i < result.size(); i++) {
                HashMap<String, String> hmPlace = result.get(i);
                lat = Double.parseDouble(hmPlace.get("lat"));
                lng = Double.parseDouble(hmPlace.get("lng"));
                name = hmPlace.get("name");
                String locality = hmPlace.get("locality");
                String city = hmPlace.get("city");
                latLng = new LatLng(lat, lng);
                markerOptions.position(latLng);
                markerOptions.title(name);
                markerOptions.snippet(locality + "," + city);
                markerOptions.icon(BitmapDescriptorFactory.fromResource(R.drawable.school_marker));
                markers.add(googleMap.addMarker(markerOptions));
                googleMap.moveCamera(CameraUpdateFactory.newLatLngZoom(new LatLng(24.66372, 93.90627), 8.0f));
            }
        }
    }
```

Answer (score 0):

You should create a HashMap for Markers.

```
private HashMap<Marker, AnyObject> msHashMap;

Marker mkr = mMap.addMarker(newMarkerOptions().position(latLng).title(anyobject.getPsName()));
msHashMap.put(mkr, anyobject);
```

Here AnyObject shall be the type of Object in which you are storing data after parsing from JSON.

And one more input
Use Volley or okHttp for REST Request Response
and GSON for parsing JSON.

Hope it helps..